# Python appending to the same row in the list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have written a piece of code that searches for directories for a text file and based on the if condition that I wrote, it copies, stores, and writes in a new file. The problem I am struggling with is that when **different if conditions appending to the same empty list**, it stores the output of the second "if condition" as a new element array. However, I want the output of multiple if conditions to be stored in the same row. To be more specific here is how my code stores and writes in a text file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from IPython import embed

import os

File = 'results.txt'
ospath = os.walk('/Users/analyses/')

mylist=[]

for subdir, dirs, files in ospath:
    if File in files:
        filepath = subdir + '/' + File
        with open(filepath) as fp:
            for line in fp:
                line_list = []
                if "Bckgnd subtracted source c/r" in line:
                    line_array = line.split(" ")
                    mylist.extend((line_array[5],line_array[7].rstrip("\n")))
                elif "Bckgnd subtracted source cnts" in line:
                    line_array = line.split(" ")
                    mylist.extend((line_array[5],line_array[7].rstrip("\n")))
                mylist.append(line_list)

mylist = np.asarray(mylist)


with open("mylist.txt", "w") as txt_file:
    for line in mylist:
        txt_file.write('\n'.join(','.join(elems) for elems in mylist))
```

Output :

```
    11.3,4.8
    id_06,BANANA
    9.3,5.6
    id_01,APPLE
    8.7, 23.8
    id_08, ORANGE
    
    mylist[0] = [11.3,4.8] #comes from first if condition
    mylist[1] = [id_06,BANANA] #comes from second if condition
```

Where the way I want it:

```
    11.3,4.8,id_06,BANANA 
    9.3,5.6,id_01,APPLE
    8.7, 23.8, id_08, ORANGE
```

where `mylist[0] = [11.3,4.8,id_06,BANANA]`

Comment: Try to use an `if` and `elif` statement instead of two `if`'s because then only one condition would be active at a time, even if both conditions are met.

Comment: I am getting the same results with elif.

Comment: Are you sure your indentations are okay? The sample you've provided has the mylist.append statements falling out of their if blocks, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if it suits your problem. But you may try the following:

```
mylist = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line_list = []
        if "condition1" in line:
            line_array = line.split(" ")
            line_list.extend([line_array[5],line_array[7].rstrip("\n")])
        if "condition2" in line:
            line_array = line.split(" ")
            line_list.extend((line_array[5],line_array[7].rstrip("\n")))
        mylist.append(line_list)

mylist = np.asarray(mylist)
```

This uses an individual list per line which is extended to yield a single list and not a list of lists as it will happen with appending data. The list is cleared for each line.
This may not be the fasted or most elegant way to do it, but it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a few line indentations in your example code may be wrong -- it seems the `for line in fp:` line should indented one level less and the `mylist.append(...)` lines should be indented one level more.

Regarding your quesiton: if I'm understanding correctly, you want the line_array from both if conditions on the same line in your mylist.txt file. Assuming this is the case, try using `array.extend(...)`:

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line_array = []
        if "condition1" in line:
            line_array = line.split(" ")
            mylist.extend([line_array[5],line_array[7].rstrip("\n")])
        if "condition2" in line:
            line_array = line.split(" ")
            mylist.append([line_array[5],line_array[7].rstrip("\n")])
```

Comment: This may lead to problems, when the first condition is fullfilled, but the second is not. In this case mylist may be extended twice and has the wrong dimensionality.

Comment: I was assuming by the presence of two if blocks in the OP that it would be acceptable for only one condition to be fulfilled and that the length of each row in the list to vary. If both conditions must be fulfiled, then surely they should be reduced to a single condition (or nested conditions) instead? Perhaps futher clarification is required.

Comment: Yea, both condition definitely occurs and I am getting wrong results both for this case and @FabianZills suggestion. In both cases, I am getting a bunch of empty lists, so it goes as 20 empty elements array, a row from condition1, a row from condition2, and 20 empty more elements then results from another text file.

Comment: Without seeing the contents of filepath, it may not be possible to debug, but blank lists implies the condition is not being met. This would not have been the case originally as your array appending occured outside the if blocks (due to the indentation issues).